# How to keep values and remove the others (attributes html string) on a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, str-replace

I want to know if is possible keep certain values and remove other with a regular expersion.

I have this code:

```
var str = '<td class="sky" data-toggle="up" id="heaven" > Link to heaven </td>';

var res = str.replace(/(data-toggle=")([a-zA-Z0-9:;\.\s\(\)\-\,]*)(")/gi, '');

console.log(res);
```

My result is the follow:

```
<td class="sky"  id="heaven" > Link to heaven </td>
```

I want to expect the result like this (inverse):

```
<td data-toggle="up" > Link to heaven </td>
```

Comment: [**DONT!**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1048572)

Comment: what's about have more attributes, or just need keep attribute 'data-toggle'?

Comment: @kerwin I was thinking keep one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[see](https://regex101.com/r/3TQ6qr/1)

```js
var str = '<td class="sky" data-toggle="up" id="heaven" > Link to heaven </td>';

var res = str.replace(/(<\w+)(\s*[\w-]+="[^"]+")*(\s*data-toggle="[^"]+")(\s*[\w-]+="[^"]+")*(\s*>)/g, '$1$3$5');

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I made this for two tags, `(<\w+)(\s*[\w-]+="[^"]+")*(\s*data-toggle="[^"]+")(\s*[\w-]+="[^"]+")*(\s*data-target="[^"]+")(\s*[\w-]+="[^"]+")*(\s*>)` $1$3$5$7, I didn't want to be greedy in my question, Thanks a lot @Kerwin.

Answer (score 0):

Then, your requirement here is to replace all existing attribute settings of a TD element with the new attribute setting `data-toggle="up"`, correct?
If so, maybe you can use the following regular expressions.
Find        : `<td .+?>(.+)</td>`
Replace     : `<td data-toggle="up" >\1</td>`